# Почему не скачивается Ruby при деплое?

Tags: docker, dokku

Все работало замечательно. Было реализовано достаточно много деплоев одной и той же конфигурацией.

Но вчера столкнулся с проблемой. Проблема возникает на шаге скачивания Ruby:

```
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 90 --max-time 60 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.3.4.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
       Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 90 --max-time 60 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.3.4.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote: /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/shell_helpers.rb:58:in `block in run!': Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 90 --max-time 60 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.3.4.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly: (LanguagePack::Fetcher::FetchError)
remote: 
remote: gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
remote: tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
remote: tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/shell_helpers.rb:52:in `times'
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/shell_helpers.rb:52:in `run!'
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/fetcher.rb:24:in `fetch_untar'
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/installers/heroku_ruby_installer.rb:22:in `block in fetch_unpack'
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/installers/heroku_ruby_installer.rb:16:in `chdir'
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/lib/language_pack/installers/heroku_ruby_installer.rb:16:in `fetch_unpack'
remote:     from /tmp/buildpackR6IT1/bin/support/download_ruby:14:in `<main>'
remote: <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
remote:     from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Все ссылки из браузера доступны.

Вчера после многочисленного перезапуска деплоя один раз все же процесс завершился успехом. Но сегодня весь день я получаю ошибку, которую привел вам выше.

В чем дело и как решить проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста?

**Техническая информация:**

- Dokku

  - .buildpacks файл:

    - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
    - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git

Comment: `Unexpected EOF in archive` скорее всего файл не докачался. по этому урлу скорость скачивания на уровне 2000 годов. так что, вполне вероятно, что файл до конца не скачивается. вы можете указать хэш сумму image-а,  попробуйте так сделать.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor можно пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor напишите имя файла, который вас интересует. У меня множество конфигов.

Comment: простите. не заметил в логе